# How to view the last GET HTTP request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, get, xmlhttprequest

How can I view the last GET http request in JavaScript? Basically what I am after is what I can see my firebug console. When XMLHttpRequests are showing in console I see a line that looks something like:

```
GET   http://www.domain.com/php/file.php?q0&c=1   200   OK   163ms
```

How do I view that URL in JavaScript?

EDIT: Just to be clear I'm looking for the URL between GET... and ...200. I don't care about anything else. I don't want any of the other info.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I ended up going with a workaround using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP and then passing it to JavaScript.

Answer (score 15):

You may want to modify the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` to [decorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) it with your "tracking" code. Something like this:

```
var ajaxCalls = [];

XMLHttpRequest.prototype._originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
   ajaxCalls.push(url);
   this._originalOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
}
```

The `ajaxCalls` array will get populated with the URLs of your Ajax requests. The last request will be at `ajaxCalls[ajaxCalls.length - 1]`.

Note that if you want to track only `GET` requests, you can simply log URLs only if `method === 'GET'` in the `open()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with a shoddy workaround using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in PHP and then passing it to JS.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's solution works, but not for IE8 and lower, as IE has different number of arguments.

Try this instead:

```
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype._original_open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    ajaxCalls.push(arguments[1]);
    this._original_open.apply(this,arguments);
};
```