# How to get current (latest) JSON get request URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid and search filters and `loadOnce=false`. I search records in grid and i am able to see this json GET type in firebug.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/items/listGrid?ticketId=&_search=true&nd=1393573713370&rows=20&page=1&sidx=id&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22summary%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22cn%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22Test%22%7D%5D%7D
```

I want to get this JSON request URL after this request completed I have to add same params to my pdf link.

I try

```
document.URL
window.location.pathname
jQuery("#itemsGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'url');
```

output

```
"localhost:8080/myapp/items/list"
"/myapp/items/list"
"/myapp/items/listGrid?ticketId="
```

How can I get the same URL?

Comment: post your javascript code

Comment: does jqGrid generate json call itself?

Comment: it dont have any code, just jqgrid library only. my request is how to get current(latest) json request url in my javascript code by using jquery or javascirpt.

Comment: i write 'test' in 'description' column filter and click enter, so i am getting that url in firebug.

Comment: You can't, there's no way to get the last URL used, you have to somehow hook into the functions in jQGrid that generates those URL's

Answer (score 0):

If it is an ajax call you could decorate the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` function:

```
var calls = [];

XMLHttpRequest.prototype._originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
   if(method === 'GET') // Only add GET requests
       calls.push(url);
   this._originalOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
}
```

Now you can access the last get URL as follows

```
var lastUrl = calls[calls.length - 1]
```

Adopted this code from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799220/how-to-view-the-last-get-http-request-in-javascript) SO question.

Comment: it need to pass user credentials, i can not post in application directly or indirectly. Have any other solution please...

Comment: @kumarM: It sounds that you need **set** URL instead of **get** it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **append** the URL with additional parameters you should use `postData` parameter of jqGrid. I recommend to define parameters as functions (like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935)). If you need to send user credentials information then you should better place it in custom HTTP headers instead of URL which can be seen by everybody. Usage of `loadBeforeSend` callback would be the best choice in the case. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5706690/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477061/315935) for the code example. One more option which you have is the usage of `beforeRequest` callback to modify `url` parameter of jqGrid directly before the usage (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6303683/315935))

The usage of `https:` instead of `http:` in the final solution would be recommend too.