# How to fetch Network data (request and response) from dev tools using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, google-chrome-devtools

I am using python with selenium for web automation.

I can draw some shape on canvas and when I click save all this shape related information is sent through request.

I want to validate this request along with corresponding response in network tab of dev tools.

How should I use execute_javascript API of selenium to do this

The ultimate goal is to validate what exactly was done on canvas. I do not want to use any OCR tools for image processing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the last GET HTTP request in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799220/how-to-view-the-last-get-http-request-in-javascript)

Comment: Edited the description

Comment: Look at the linked question - you may be able to intercept the ajax request that is sent, and validate it. What you ask in the description - Selenium to interact with the DevTools, is simply not possible - SE does not have access on that level (a desktop's app components). You might be able to do it with other tools that interact with apps - AutoIt, or java's Robot framework (**not** to be confused with the generic automation Robotframework) , but not through selenium.